# Rendering Highcharts legend using HTML causes issue with positioning/spacing

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I want to float my legend and put it on the top of my chart. I also want to put in custom symbols.

Before i could add my custom symbols which i'm not sure hoiw to do i am getting an issue aligning the legend correctly when using the 'useHTML' option.

Here is a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zavbw1py/)

Cant anyone figure what i am doing wrong or is this a bug with highcharts

Podge

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            floating: true,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            itemWidth:100,
            symbolPadding:0,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            useHTML:true,
            x: -10,
            y:45,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: The legend is positioned according to your options in the chart and css - how exactly do you want the legend to look?

Comment: the symbols are not beside their label. and they are different distances apart for each of them and i son't understand why.

Comment: Each text's span has width 70px and and the text is right aligned - but each text has different width, so the distance between the symbol and the text will be different for each legend item. Can you make a picture how the legend should look like?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact issue.  I found that removing useHTML:true from the legend, makes it work.  This is a bug!